# Confusing of the nth power example

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

[image: question]

I got this question on the book. And the answer for this question is

[image: answer]
I understand how to get part a and part b.
I just confusing about part c. What I got is R^2 = (2 1 1; 1 2 1; 1 1 2).

I followed nth power definition that I used R*R. On that answer on the book, he used rth boolean power to solve this question. I am so confusing now which one is wrong. If this part should use rth boolean power, I think the question should be marked as $R^{[r]}$. For example, first row and first column number resulting from 1*0+1*1+1*1=2

Comment: All that matters is that the entries are nonzero. Treat all zero entries as zero, and all nonzero entries as one in this context. Replacing the twos with ones should make answer clear. Instead of looking at this from the perspective of matrices, one could look at this from the perspective of a directed graph.  $R^2$ would be all the pairs $(x,y)$ such that there is a directed path of length two from $x$ to $y$. It should be clear that for this example, all such pairs work. E.g. $3\to 3\to 1$ so $(3,1)$ is included, $3\to 1\to 2$ so $(3,2)$ is included, and $3\to 3\to 3$ so $(3,3)$ is included.

Comment: If your question stems from the notation used and why it was marked $R^2$ instead of $R^{[2]}$, note that $R$ is a *relation* and $R^2$ is perfectly understood.  It is the *matrix representation of $R$* which is being raised to a boolean power.  If you prefer to notate it that way, then sure, it is $M_R^{[2]}$ instead of $M_R^{2}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh,I see. So if the matrix is representing a relation but not just a general matrix, then I should use boolean power.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the author is working over the Boolean domain $\mathbb{B} = \{0,1\}$, in which case $1+1=1$, or in other words, $2=1$. So $$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$